# Trouble with extra character while using 'write.table'

Tags: r, write.table

I am using R 3.3.4 and RStudio 1.1.453. I am creating lines of data passed from a function call, then using `write.table()` to write one line (and only one line) of data into one file at a time to obtain a .tsv.

I know it's a noobie question but so am i. :)

```
for (i in 1:n) {
write.table(make_line(),
            file = (paste("file", i, ".tsv", sep = "")),
            quote = FALSE,
            eol = "\r\n",
            sep = '\t'
            )
}
```

However my output is:

```
x
1   >chr4   820383   966802   CAC   TRUE
```

when `make_line()` generates below and that is all I want:

```
>chr4   820383   966802   CAC   TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are default row and column names.  To avoid them, set `row.names` and `col.names` to `FALSE` in `write.table`.

```
write.table("AAAA")
# "x"
# "1" "AAAA"

write.table("AAAA", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
# "AAAA"
```